# What happens if the greater limit becomes smaller when you change them for u-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If I am doing u-substitution on a definite integral, and my upper limit is $b$ and my lower limit is $a$, and I change the limits to match the u, what happens if my $b$ turns out to be lower than my $a$ (so the now b is smaller than a)?

Does my new b still go at the top, or must I maintain the order?

For example, if $u = 1 + cosx$, and $b = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $a = \frac{\pi}{3}$, when I change them, I get $b = 1$, and $a = 1.5$.

Now $a$ is greater than $b$.

So which goes at the top of the integral sign (which is the upper limit)?

Comment: There is no rule saying that the upper limit of an integral has to be greater than the lower limit.

Comment: For some reason I was taught that! So in this case, after my new u limits, I will just make sure to maintain the order as is, right? You do have to maintain order... am I right? I mean, you can't switch the two else after u-substitution or you'll get the negative of the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  It's usually conventional to write an integral with the lower limit less than the upper, but it's perfectly fine not to have this hold. Just make the substitution and don't switch the order!

Comment: When we first learn about integrals through the "area under a curve" motivation, it's just easier to assume $a \lt b$ (and $f(x) \ge 0$). But when we start learning the rules it turns out we don't need these at all and all our transformations are still valid. Kind of like we use $(x + y) + z = x +(y+z)$ without worrying if any of the numbers are negative. You can even end up trusting the transformation rules more than your intuition.

Answer (score 2):

$ \int_b^a u(x) dx= - \int_a^b u(x) dx.$